# Fatty acid oxidation in adrenal medulla?

Tags: biochemistry, cell-biology, metabolism, human-physiology, energy

Why adrenal medulla can not utilise fatty acids for generation of energy?
What could be the benefit for not having ability to use fatty acids?

[Refrence 1](http://www.biologydiscussion.com/metabolism/metabolism-of-lipids-5-cycles-with-diagram/11219)

[Refrence 2](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=Bd9XAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA288&lpg=PA288&dq=brain,%20erythrocytes%20and%20adrenal%20medulla%20cannot%20utilize%20fatty%20acids%20for%20energy%20requirement.&source=bl&ots=_1v7-U_cK2&sig=z-0PX6iX9PZHjrMrIdcI80hIv2Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-56rD1YbSAhWEgI8KHaxDBLYQ6AEIOjAF#v=onepage&q=brain%2C%20erythrocytes%20and%20adrenal%20medulla%20cannot%20utilize%20fatty%20acids%20for%20energy%20requirement.&f=false)

Comment: Does it have something to do with feedback mechanism?

Comment: Interesting question. Do you have a reference showing that fatty acids cannot be used? The adrenal medulla is basically a specialized nervous tissue, and neurons are usually considered to be unable to oxidize fatty acids, but other cell types in the CNS do oxidize fatty acids, see for example https://www.hindawi.com/journals/bmri/2014/472459/

Comment: but the blood brain barrier is not present in adrenal medulla.

Comment: I was hoping for a reference to actual experimental data, rather than just somebody else claiming the same thing. I did find some textbooks that repeat this statement (without reference), so perhaps it's valid, but textbooks can also be inaccurate ... Also, the blood-brain barrier does allow fatty acid transport (contrary to statements in some textbooks :), see for example https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17901540  See also my related question http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/34159/why-is-the-brain-dependent-on-glucose

Comment: Also, we should consider the possibility that there is no benefit. Some features of biology are not good for the organism, but evolution just hasn't come up with any better solution.